# CodeIgniter - No cookies to be set unless agreed to by the visitor

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Is there a simple way to make sure no cookies are set by CodeIgniter (ci_session) unless agreed to by the visitor?

"In the UK a new Cookie Regulation officially announced on 20th May 2011 and will be enforced from May 2012 that website owners must gain a visitor’s consent that they will be tracked by cookies on that website."

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: My understanding of the Cookie Law is that you only need explicit permission to use cookies for targeted advertising. Session cookies do not fall under that bucket, and thus you are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Although a session cookie (ci_session) CI records the users IP which could be classed as user identifiable information could it not? Which I'm not entirely sure but I believe would need explicit permission to record/store?

Comment: See http://www.international-chamber.co.uk/components/com_wordpress/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/icc_uk_cookie_guide.pdf. I cannot vouch for the authenticity of that document, but it's what I see people using as a reference.

Comment: Thanks to all, for the mean time we've decided to add a disclaimer after the cookies have been created. It was the simplist option and considering some of the larger online companies haven't even got any info regarding cookies atleast it shows we're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, to track if a user wanted to use a cookie, you would almost need a cookie to know that :)

But thinking aloud - the solution would be to not create any cookies on the main page. Then in your view have a link: "click here if you accept cookies"

which directs to /yourcontroller/turnoncookies function

then in your function, load the session class, and create the cookie.

Comment: Thanks. Having a main page and then setting cookies after would work but that means all new visitors must go past one screen everytime they visit the website. It would upset a lot of visitors. I'm hoping to come up with a solution that allows them access to the whole site but they just cannot log in or set user preferences until they click agree on an informational bar like the example attached, any additional ideas?

Comment: In that case you need to basically use AJAX - and if they click "I agree" then it sets a cookie with something like jQuery Cookies?

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to disable CodeIgniter sessions when the page loads as by default the ci_session is created automatically when the first page is visited?